# TextView align second line text to start of first line when text gravity is center

Tags: android, textview, text-alignment

I have this TextView which has gravity to center

```
 <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="this is first line text\nsecond line"
            app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="18sp"
            app:autoSizeMinTextSize="12sp"
            app:autoSizeStepGranularity="1sp"
            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

[image]

How it's possible to align `"second line"` to the start of first line `"this is first line text`" ?

Answer (score 0):

Use gravity: Start instead of center.

Then to place your text evenly in your textview add some padding horizontally and vertically to your textview.

Comment: How to get value of `some` padding ?

Comment: Play with the adding number like around 10dp will work for you...if not increase or decrease it as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `android:gravity` to `center` aligns the TextView content to the center horizontally (and vertically). If you want all paragraphs to be aligned to the left you can set gravity to `start`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `width` of TextView to `wrap_content`, leave `gravity` to default(left) and set `layout_gravity` to `center` (it will center your `TextView` inside the parent)

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="this is first line text\nsecond line"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `android:layout_width="match_parent"` with`android:layout_width="wrap_content"`

And replace `android:gravity="center"` with `android:gravity="start"`

**Output**

[image]